# How to remove one of the incorrect choices from a multiple choice quiz in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a quiz app.

I want to add an extra hint feature where after the user presses the hint button at the side, one of the options of the quiz app disappears. However, right now when I press the hint button all my options disappear. I suspect this is because my `if` statement is wrong.

```
var currentQuestion = 0
var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0

//hint button, making the option disappear

@IBAction func hintButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    for actionButton in actionButtons {
        if actionButton.currentTitle != String(rightAnswerPlacement)
            //this if condition is wrong, rightAnswerPlacement is a tag/ number where the correct answer lies (i think )
        {
            actionButton.isHidden = true // true to hide the button
        }
    }
} 

@IBOutlet weak var hintButton: UIButton!

//Label for qs
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

//button for choices

@IBOutlet var actionButtons: [UIButton]!

@IBAction func Action(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
    {
        print("Right")
        
    }
    else
    {
        print("Wrong")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "That is incorrect", message: "Try again!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true)
        currentQuestion -= 1
        //how to record which wrong answer the user is pressing
        //let WrongAnswer = sender.tag.titleLabel?.text
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `rightAnswerPlacement` as the tag of the button you never want to hide, then you could generate a random number within range of the number of answers but excluding the tag in rightAnswerPlacement.

Please add this extension outside your ViewController:

```
extension Int {
static func random(upperBound: Int, avoidingNumber: Int) -> Int {
    guard upperBound > 0 else { return 0 }
    var number = Int.random(in: 0...upperBound - 1)
    if number == avoidingNumber {
        number = upperBound
    }
    return number
}
```

Using this extension, when the user taps the hint button you should generate a random number for the incorrect answer you want to hide and then find the button with the randomTag just generated and hide it.

```
let randomTag = Int.random(upperBound: 3, avoidingNumber: rightAnswerPlacement)
for actionButton in actionButtons where actionButton.tag == randomTag {
    actionButton.isHidden == true
}
```

This way when someone presses the hint button a random incorrect answer will always get hidden.

Comment: hi rightAnswerPlacement is actually a variable and a placeholder for my right answer so I want to hide any of the other three choices but the correct answer one.

Comment: so after using your suggestion, my code is making all the choices but one disappear and I only want one option to disappear at a time

Comment: Hi! I get it now, please check my edited answer, hope it helps

Comment: HI, this definitely helps my situation thank you for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I would really appreciate if you could mark my answer as selected if it resolved your question. Greetings!

Comment: Apologies, but just a follow-up enquiry. As I move on to the next question, that one option is hidden from the previous qs when I pressed the hint button. So I want all the options to restart as I move on to the next qs.

Comment: Of course, no problem. When you pass on to the next question you should loop through all of your questions and if one of them is hidden, set actionButton.isHidden == false to make it visible again.